# Passing parameters to an rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to pass extra parameters to an rspec test, as such (the extra paramaters are two arrays, guest_value and bar_value):

```
        it "should create an outing" do 
            lambda do 
                post :create, :outing => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:outing), :guest_value => [55,66], :bar_value => [66,77]
            end.should change(Outing, :count).by(1)
        end
```

However, my test completely ignores them, as though they're not even there.

Additionally, the syntax:

```
                post :create, :outing => { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:outing), :guest_value => [55,66], :bar_value => [66,77] }
```

kicks up an error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

which is a result of my Controller code:

```
def create
@outing = Outing.new(params[:outing])

@outing.user_id = @user.id

if @outing.save 

    params[:guestvalue].each do |guest_id|
        @outing.add_guest(guest_id)
    end 

    params[:barvalue].each do |bar_id|
        @outing.add_bar(bar_id)
    end 

    TimeRange.create(:element_id => @outing.id, :element_type => 'outing', :start_time => params[:day][:start_time], :end_time => params[:day][:end_time])  

    flash[:notice] = "Outing created successfully!" 

    redirect_to @outing
else 
    flash[:notice] = "Error creating outing!"
    @outing = Outing.new
    render(new_outing_path)
end
```

end

Comment: Couldn't be that your calling `:guest_value` and `:bar_value` while your controller is checking `params[:guestvalue]` and `params[:barvalue]` (no underscore), could it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you definitely need the curly braces for the command to do what you want (pass the arrays to the factorygirl function). Post the error and maybe I can help more?

reagan

Comment: either `:barvalue` or `guestvalue` doesn't have the method `.each`, and I'm assuming it's because in the test you name them `:bar_value` and `:guest_value`. hope that helps